# Show f is strictly increasing on [a,b] if cts on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,c) and (c,b)

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

Where a < c < b and f'(x) > 0 for all x in (a,c), (c,b).

Using the Mean Value Theorem I have shown that the f is strictly increasing on [a,c) and (c,b]; my question is: **how do I involve c in this so that f is strictly increasing on [a,b]?**

Here is my thinking (and I realize it's not particularly thorough!):

We have shown that f is strictly increasing on [a,c), (c,b] and since f is continuous on [a,b] we must have that f'(c) is greater than or equal to zero (otherwise we would have discontinuity of f at x = c) ( then maybe look at left and right hand limits at x = c?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's incorrect in part because there is no reason to assume that $f'(c)$ exists.  Sketch two line segments with positive but different slopes, attached at $x=c$, to see that $f'(c)$ might not exist.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yeah I see that now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then $f(c) = \lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)$. As $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a, c)$, taking $x \rightarrow c^-$ in the limit, $f(c) > f(x)$ for all $x < c$ (why?). Similarly, $f(c) < f(x)$ for all $x > c$. Then you may conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a, b]$ (why?).